# Why use babel-loader since webpack already uses terser which minifies es6+ codes?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, babel-loader, terser

By default webpack uses terser which can minify es6+ codes.I have successfully run es6+ codes in ie after building with webpack.

So,whats the point of using babel-loader with webpack?

Comment: It is used to transpile JavaScript files using Babel. It's not about minification.

Comment: @paul if minification is working without transpiling,why do we need to transpile?in the terser official site,they also said you dont need to transpile es6 first using babel

Comment: To make ES6, ES7 javascript code work in browsers which only supports ES5.

Comment: Please read my comments carefully.I am saying that without using babel-loader,those es6 codes are working fine in es5 browsers (because terser plugin is making es6 to es5).so why we need to use babel-loader since i am already getting the job done without using it?

Comment: Ah, sorry. Yes, you don't need babel then.